# Eclipse 3.2 or 3.4?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there really a big difference between Eclipse 3.2 and 3.4? I am currently using 3.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the 'New and Noteworthy' pages for a list of new features.

- [3.3 New and Noteworthy](http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news.html)
- [3.4 New and Noteworthy](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news.html)

Personally, from using 3.4 day-to-day, the improvements are probably not hugely noticeable individually, but the overall experience is much better. If I have to go back to 3.3 or 3.2 I frequently find things that don't work as I expect, and think 'Ah yes, that didn't work in 3.2'.

Comment: Luke - what? Please see the dropins section - it makes adding plugins w/o update sites SO MUCH EASIER than that crappy .eclipseExtension crud before.

http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news-part1.html

Answer (score 2):

Read

- [Eclipse 3.3 - New and Noteworthy](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news-part1.html)
- [Eclipse 3.4 - New and Noteworthy](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news.html)

and for the upcoming Galieleo release

- [Eclipse 3.5 - Galileo - New and Noteworthy](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/12/10/eclipse-3-5-galileo-new-and-noteworthy)

If you use CDT than there were **major** improvements (indexer, code completion, ...) that you definitely want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll be interested in upgrading again to 3.6!

[Eclipse 3.6 - Helios - New and Noteworthy](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/10/15/eclipse-3-6-helios-new-and-noteworthy)

Answer (score 0):

I switched, but saw no big improvements.  The switch was pretty painless though, so I'd say "Why Not?".

Comment: I am using the default installed version in Ubuntu currently and wanted the package manager to handle upgrades.